# Ggplot2 shows the wrong month

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following table

```
df <- structure(list(Month = structure(1:12, .Label = c("2021-01-31", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-31", "2021-04-30", "2021-05-31", "2021-06-30", "2012-01-31", "2012-02-29", "2012-03-31", "2012-04-30", "2012-05-31", "2012-06-30"), class = "factor"), AvgVisits = c(6.98655104580674,7.66045407330464, 7.69761337479304, 7.54387561322994, 7.24483848458728, 6.32001400498928, 6.66794871794872, 7.207780853854, 7.60281201431308, 6.70113837397123, 6.57634103019538, 6.75321935568936)), .Names = c("Month","AvgVisits"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

df$Month <- as.Date(df$Month)
```

I'm using the following code to create a graph. It should start on Jan, but it starts on Feb and I don't understand why

```
df %>%

  filter(Month>as.Date("2021-01-01")) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x=Month, y=AvgVisits))+

  geom_col()+

  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y")
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Your dates are at the end of each month, so the graph is plotting the 'closest' month, i.e. your first bar is centred over the 31st January, but the 'closest' label is the 1st Feb (this is what people generally want). You can easily alter your plot to suit, e.g. @akrun's answer below

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use [`floor_date`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.3.3/topics/floor_date) from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(Month>as.Date("2021-01-01")) %>% 
   mutate(Month = floor_date(Month, 'month')) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=Month, y=AvgVisits))+ 
   geom_col()+ 
   scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y")
```

-output

[image]